# Apply currency format on ion input

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, angular-directive

I want to put a currency format on an ion input but angular directives doesn't work as they do on HTML input [Ion-Input not working with directives but regular input does](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-input-not-working-with-directives-but-regular-input-does/75074).

So I've been trying to do something like they said in here [Input currency mask - IONIC](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-input-currency-mask-ionic/106398/4)  and here [Ion-Input currency format](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-input-currency-format/88963/8) but none of them works for me.

One problem is that I have a programmatically generated form, the structure comes from a service like this:

```
    value: 20000,
    key: varKey,
    label: varLabel,
    required: true,
    order: 0,
    controlType: 'textbox',
    type: 'number',
    formula: 'return other_var + 50',
    dependencies: ['other_var'],
    category: 'varCategory'
```

So some input changes makes other value to changes, if other_var changes (the user types a new value in the input) varKey needs to be recalculated according to the *formula* property. This is how I create the input:

```
<ion-input [id]="key" [formControlName]="key" [type]="type" [ngModel]="value |  currency:'USD':'symbol-narrow'"
 (ngModelChange)="formValueChanges($event,key)" text-right></ion-input>
```

This gives me this error *InvalidPipeArgument: '$20,000.00' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'*. So I imported the **CurrencyPipe** into my component to do something like this (following the Ion-input currency format post):

```
<ion-input [id]="key" [formControlName]="key" [type]="type" [ngModel]="getCurrencyFormat(value)"
 (ngModelChange)="formValueChanges($event,key)" text-right></ion-input>
```

And the *getCurrencyFormat* function is this:

```
getCurrencyFormat(value: number): string {
    if (value) {
      console.log('Input value: ', value)
      if (!value.toString().includes('$')) {
        return this.currencyPipe.transform(value, 'USD', true, '1.2-2');
      }
    }
  }
```

This doesn't give me any errors but none of the values are displayed.

The *formValueChanges* function binds the typed value with the model and recalculate the values that has been affected.

At this point I don't know how to apply a currency format to an input without creating a cycle, because the function that applies the format triggers the function that recalculated the values.